# HighCharts - Remove space between series on stacked bar

Tags: jquery, space, highcharts, stacked

I have a HighCharts chart to display some information. I have stacked information for each day. Each entry is unique -> I cannot use a single series.

The problem is: between two days, there's a huge space and I have no idea how to decrease or remove this.
There's no effect when I play with the PlotOptions.
I think the reason is my xAxis-Handling, because if I use the "normal way" to declare the xAxis categies, there's no problem.

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MhL2Q/1/

Another, working jsFiddle: jsfiddle_dot_net/wergeld/M85tL/ (just 2 links allowed)

Original HighChart DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

Comment: What if you just set your container height to 200px?

Comment: @MikeRobinson  To play with the height could be the right way. But take a look on http://jsfiddle.net/MhL2Q/3/ - you can see, that the line 1 and 3 is just the half height of line 2

Comment: Cool to see one of my fiddles being referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [xAxis.minPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minPadding) and [xAxis.maxPadding](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.maxPadding)

> Padding of the max value relative to the length of the axis. A padding
>   of 0.05 will make a 100px axis 5px longer. This is useful when you
>   don't want the highest data value to appear on the edge of the plot
>   area. When the axis' max option is set or a max extreme is set using
>   axis.setExtremes(), the maxPadding will be ignored. Defaults to 0.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        month: '%e. %b',
        year: '%b'
    },
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    tickWidth: 1,
    minPadding: 0.5,
    maxPadding: 0.5                
}
```

[Padding datetime axis @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/kZa2s/)

Comment: @DerAbt Cheers :) Glad to help!!! Did i mention that highcharts has an awesome documentation with even more awesome examples @ http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts should come handy to you the next time

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YSfkQ/) meet your needs? You need to remove all paddings in the chart.